# MemoryStream closed error

Tags: c#

I am using `iTextSharp` to generate a `PDF` and wan't to save it to a bucket in S3. I have keep getting error like this "Cannot access a closed stream".

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfWriter outputWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(newPDF, ms);
    newPDF.Open();
    PdfContentByte cb1 = outputWriter.DirectContent;
    for (int pagesToAddFromSourcePDFToNewPDF = 0; pagesToAddFromSourcePDFToNewPDF < soa_total_pages; pagesToAddFromSourcePDFToNewPDF++)
    {
        if (pagesToAddFromSourcePDFToNewPDF > 0)
        {
            currentPageInSourcePDF++;
        }

        newPDF.NewPage();
        PdfImportedPage page = outputWriter.GetImportedPage(sourcePDF, currentPageInSourcePDF);
        cb1.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
    }

    filesCreated++;
    // Upload stream to AWS
    ms.Position = 0;
    using (var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client))
    {
        transferUtility.Upload(ms, "mybucketname", "1/soa/" + newPDFFilename); // ERROR IS THROWN HERE
    }

    newPDF.Close();
}
```

Any ideas?

/Bob

Comment: It seems iTextSharp closes the stream by itself. Where exactly does the exception occur?

Comment: If I put a watch on MS, i see that the exception is thrown when transferUtility() executes. But, the code goes down to newPDF.Close() before it actually jumps down to the catch handle.

Comment: Note that if I use a FileStream, it works like a charm. But that is when I save locally for testing.

Comment: the exception occurs on transferUtility.Upload, yet it still executes newPdf.Close()? That does not make sense.

Comment: I know. Don't know if newPDF executes, but the actual catch occurs on that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the stream twice: once to create the PDF in memory, and a second time to upload it. Reuse of a stream can be problematic when you don't know what happens to it by the abstractions (in this case iTextSharp). Instead, convert the stream to a byte array and create a new stream from the array.

```
byte[] bytes;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    PdfWriter outputWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(newPDF, ms);
    newPDF.Open();
    PdfContentByte cb1 = outputWriter.DirectContent;

    for (int pagesToAddFromSourcePDFToNewPDF = 0; pagesToAddFromSourcePDFToNewPDF < soa_total_pages; pagesToAddFromSourcePDFToNewPDF++)
    {
        if (pagesToAddFromSourcePDFToNewPDF > 0)
        {
            currentPageInSourcePDF++;
        }

        newPDF.NewPage();
        PdfImportedPage page = outputWriter.GetImportedPage(sourcePDF, currentPageInSourcePDF);
        cb1.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
    }

    newPDF.Close();

    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

filesCreated++;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    // Upload stream to AWS
    using (var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client))
    {
        transferUtility.Upload(ms, "mybucketname", "1/soa/" + newPDFFilename);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, man, I was really stuck. Work great now, owe you one!